# Overlap images cross over table cell border in CSS or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this HTML table(in Javascript) and CSS which generates the green arrows in the cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>  
        <td><div id="ArrowImage1"></div><td>
        <td><div id="ArrowImage2"></div><td> 
        <td><div id="ArrowImage3"></div><td> 
        <td><div id="ArrowImage4"></div><td> 
        <td></td>   
    </tr>
</table>

#ArrowImage1 {

    background: url(../images/greenArrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    float: left;    
}
#ArrowImage2 {

    background: url(../images/greenArrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    float: left;    
}
#ArrowImage3 {

    background: url(../images/greenArrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    float: left;    
}
#ArrowImage4 {

    background: url(../images/greenArrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    float: left;    
}
```

However, I'm trying to make the arrows overlap on top of each other from left to right cell. (the images are transparent). How do I approach on this in order to properly overlap images cross over the borders? or can this be done by Javascript? if so, could you refer to an example? Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be in a table?

Comment: yes it has to be a table which is the issue i'm having

Comment: Make table cells smaller and absolute-position the arrow images (as img elements, not as backgrounds), allowing them to overflow their `td` container.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
   img {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

The **z-index** controls depth-order, higher z-index items appear in front of lower numbered z-index items.